# Kubernetes Ingress. Send http traffic to a port and https traffic to other port

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Using k8s ingress, is it possible using the same domain send incoming http traffic to a port and https traffic to other port?

I have not find anything in the ingress sepecification to do it or annotations in nginx-ingress-controller

Comment: That configuration more like at physical load balancer i.e TCP/UDP layer. The `nginx-ingress` works at HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two objects i.e, service and ingress for this. You need to configure ingress similar to below:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: abc.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 80
        path: /uiaccesscontrol
      - backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 443
        path: /uiaccesscontrol
```

and service will have configurations similar as given below:

```
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: https
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
```

Now, https traffic will be routed to secure port 443 and http to 80.

Comment: more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459015/how-to-configure-ingress-to-direct-traffic-to-an-https-backend-using-https/54459898

Comment: The ingress config above for a 2nd backend with servicePort 443 does not work for me. The config works (also for port 443) after removing the 2nd backend.

Comment: the most obvious solution, but it does not work! ingress converts http/https traffic to http and then send it to some of ports