# How NGINX Ingress controller back-end protocol annotation works in path based routing?

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm currently playing with NGINX ingress controller in my k8s cluster. I was trying to make end-to-end encryption work and I was able to make the connection secure all the way to the pod.

In order to achieve HTTPS all the way till pod, I had to use annotation

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
```

Sample Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: foo-api-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - foo.example.com
    secretName: foo-cert
  rules:
  - host: foo.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /path1
        backend:
          serviceName: foo-api-path1-service
          servicePort: 443
      - path: /path2
        backend:
          serviceName: foo-api-path2-service
          servicePort: 443
```

I'm confused in terms of how exactly this happens because when we encrypt the connection path also get encrypted then how NGINX does path-based routing? does it decrypt the connection at ingress and re-encrypt it? also, does performance get affected by using this method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> does it decrypt the connection at ingress and re-encrypt it?

In short, yes. Please see the explanation below.

---

#### Explanation

The path that a request is travelling to get to a `Pod` can be seen as:

[image: REQUEST-PATH]

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*

Assuming that we have an `Ingress controller` (`nginx-ingress`) in place of an `Ingress` you can have several ways to connect your client with a `Pod` (simplified):

- Unencrypted:

  - `client` -- (HTTP) --> `Ingress controller` -- (HTTP) --> `Service` ----> `Pod`

---

- Encrypted at the `Ingress controller` (with `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"`)

  - `client` -- (HTTP) --> `Ingress controller` -- (HTTP**S**) --> `Service` ----> `Pod`

---

- Encrypted and decrypted at the `Ingress controller` where [TLS Termination](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/tls-termination/#tls-termination) happens:

  - `client` -- (HTTP**S**) --> `Ingress controller` (TLS Termination) -- (HTTP) --> `Service` ----> `Pod`

---

**Your setup:**

- Encrypted and decrypted at the `Ingress` controller where [TLS Termination](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/tls-termination/#tls-termination) happens and **encrypted once again** when connecting with a HTTPS backend by `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"`:

  - `client` -- (HTTP**S**) --> `Ingress controller` (TLS Termination) -- (HTTP**S**) --> `Service` ----> `Pod`

---

- Encrypted and decrypted at the `Pod` where `Ingress controller` is configured with [SSL Passthrough](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#ssl-passthrough):

  - `client` -- (HTTP**S**) --> `Ingress controller` -- (HTTP**S**) --> `Service` ----> `Pod`

> **Disclaimer!**
>
> This is only a simplified explanation. For more reference you can look at this comment:
>
> > there is a missing detail here, the SSL Passthrough traffic never reaches NGINX in the ingress controller. There is a go listener for TLS connections that just pipes the traffic to the service defined in the ingress.
> >
> > - *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress nginx: Issues: 5618](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/5618)*

---

---

For more reference you can look on the similar question (with an answer):

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: How to configure ingress to direct traffic to an https backend using https](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459898/12257134)*

You can also check this article with example setup similar to yours:

- *[Code.oursky.com: How to enable tls https between your kubernetes ingress and back end deployments](https://code.oursky.com/how-to-enable-tls-https-between-your-kubernetes-ingress-and-back-end-deployments/)*

---

Additional resources:

- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress nginx: Is it possible to have secure backend connections from the nginx controller?](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6142)*
- *[Github.com: Kubernetes: Ingress nginx: Nginx configuration: Annotations: Backend certificate authentication](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#backend-certificate-authentication)*