# kubernetes ingress service doesn't fwd in http or https

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm using on W10 dockerHub 20.10.2 and the embedded kubernetes cluster.
I have installed the [ingress-nginx controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/kubectl-plugin/), without any additional configuration.
Then created an ingress service in my namespace following the below yaml. The port is 443 in ingress, but also in the service, deployment, as the docker image is listening to 443.

****[EDIT]** see below issue is also in HTTP listening to port 4000**

**budget-ingress.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: budget-ingress
  labels:
    app: budget
  namespace: budget-namespace
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "dwpbudget.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: budget-service
                
                port:
                  number: 443
```

However, as shown in the image below, the port remains 80, whereas it should be 443.
[image: port mismatch]

the result is of course a 502 error when I'm visiting my page

the describe gives the following
[image: describe of the service]

Note that when forwarding the 443 port using `kubectl port-forward budget-deployment-59cdb8898d-2zhr4  443:443 -n budget-namespace`, everything is fine.

What am I missing here ?

here is the service yaml file

**budget-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: budget-service
  namespace: budget-namespace
  labels:
    app: budget
spec:
  selector:
    app: budget
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
```

Comment: What have you installed in the first place is the `kubectl plugin` responsible for communication with `nginx-ingress controller`. As you've posted in the comments under your answer [this link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#prerequisite-generic-deployment-command), you have provisioned `nginx-ingress controller` required by an `Ingress` resource (hence it's working). As for general guideline about `HTTPS` with `nginx-ingress` please take a look here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/

Comment: see my comment below, I changed controller, now this is fine

Answer (score 0):

update of logs when switching to HTTP, listening to port 4000, same issue, on browser `http://dwpbudget.com:4000 or http://dwpbudget.com:80` failed. Or course forwarding the port to the containers makes things ok

**logs inside the container**
[image: logs inside the container]

**ingress describe**
[image: describe of ingress]

[image]

Comment: finally I changed the ngnix controller and HTTP is working fine. Using this one : https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#prerequisite-generic-deployment-command

Answer (score 0):

There are some concepts in this question and the answer provided by original poster that I think should be addressed:

- `Nginx-ingress` installation on `Docker Desktop`:

By default `Docker Desktop` spawned Kubernetes cluster does not come with out of the box `Ingress` controller. It needs to be deployed via various measures. One is located here:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: Deploy](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)*

A link used here:

> I'm using on W10 dockerHub 20.10.2 and the embedded kubernetes cluster.
> I have installed the [ingress-nginx controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/kubectl-plugin/), without any additional configuration.

Is a link to install a **kubectl plugin** to have certain features built-in into `kubectl` related to `nginx-ingress`. This is not a link to deploy `Ingress nginx` controller which is necessary to support setup like in question.

> A side note!
>
> Example of a "feature" this `kubectl` plugin provides:
>
> - `$ kubectl ingress-nginx ingresses`
>
> ```sh
> INGRESS NAME    HOST+PATH   ADDRESSES   TLS   SERVICE   SERVICE PORT   ENDPOINTS
> nginx-ingress   /                       NO    nginx     80             1
> ```

---

I've already explained how the communication between your client, `nginx-ingress` controller and your `Pod` behaves here. I encourage everyone to check it:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: How NGINX Ingress controller back-end protocol annotation works in path based routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64662822/12257134)*

By default `NGINX Ingress` controller comes with self signed certificate:

- `Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate`

You can connect to your `Ingress` controller with `HTTPS` (when it's not specified in `Ingress` definition) but this certificate will not be valid and won't be included in the `Ingress` manifest.

To have the connection between client and `Ingress` controller with your own certificate you will need to have (in your `Ingress` resource manifest) following section:

```yaml
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - https-example.foo.com
    secretName: testsecret-tls
```

If your `Pod` is expecting `HTTPS` traffic you'll need to configure your `Ingress` manifest to send the `HTTPS` requests to your `backend` with following annotation (by default it's: `HTTP`):

- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"`

> A side note!
>
> As an alternative you can use [SSL Passthrough](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#ssl-passthrough)

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/)*
- *[Kubernees.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*