# kubernetes on gcp create an https Load Balancer with yaml

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-service

In my project I have to create a kubernetes cluster on my GCP with an External Load Balancer service for my django app. I create it with this `yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mydjango
  namespace: test1
  labels:
    app: mydjango
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: mydjango
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I apply it and all work is done on my cluster except for the fact that kubernetes create a Load balancer using `http`.

How can I modify my `yaml` to create the same Load Balancer using `https` instead `http` using my google managed certs?

So many thanks in advance
Manuel

Answer (score 1):

If you want to serve HTTPS, you need a certificate. For that, you can follow this documentation with [Google managed certificates](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/managed-certs).

You also have to define an ingress to route the traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I whole wholeheartedly agree with the answer provided by @guillaume blaquiere.

You should use following guide to have the `HTTPS` connection to your Django.

I would also like to add some additional information/resources to the whole question.

---

Addressing the following statement:

> I apply it and all work done on my cluster except for the fact that kubernetes create a Load balancer using http.

**In fact you are creating a network load balancer** (layer 4), (**`TCP`**/`UDP`):

> When you create a Service of type LoadBalancer, a Google Cloud controller wakes up and configures a network load balancer in your project. The load balancer has a stable IP address that is accessible from outside of your project.
>
> -- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Concepts: Service: Service of type LoadBalancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#services_of_type_loadbalancer)*

This type of a load balancer will forward the packets to its destination but it won't be able to accomplish things like path based routing or SSL termination.

To have the ability to connect to your Django app with HTTPS you can:

- Use [GKE Ingress for HTTP(S) Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) (as pointed by guillaume blaquiere)

In the whole process you will be using an `Ingress` resource to forward the traffic to the specific backend. Your `Ingress` controller will also be responsible for handling `SSL`.

> A side note!
>
> I'd reckon you could change the `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` to a `Service` of type `NodePort`.

You final `Ingress` definition will look similar to the one below:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: INGRESS_NAME
  namespace: test1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: ADDRESS_NAME
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: CERTIFICATE_NAME
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: mydjango
      port:
        number: 8080
```

**Alternatively** you can:

- Use different `Ingress` controller like `nginx-ingress` and add the certificate to handle the `HTTPS` either by (this will not use Google managed certificate):

  - [Kubernetes.github.io: Ingress nginx: User guide: TLS](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/)
  - [Cert-manager.io: Docs: Installation: Kubernetes](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/kubernetes/)

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/)*

I'd reckon you could also take a look on this answer (on how the communication is happening with `nginx-ingress`):

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: How NGINX Ingress controller back-end protocol annotation works in path based routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64647258/how-nginx-ingress-controller-back-end-protocol-annotation-works-in-path-based-ro/64662822#64662822)*